# How to add a responsive drop down menu to an existing responsive menu without Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I have create a responsive menu that becomes sticky on scroll. Everything works perfectly but I can not add a drop down link to any of the link. [Most tutorials](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly) I have found were not really accurate nor responsive and could not really help me modify [**my existing responsive menu**](http://usefaith.patronempire.com/test3.php).

Here is the code used for my existing responsive menu

Css

```
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0 auto; /* pour centrer le menu */
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;

    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    width:1400px; /* pour centrer le menu */
    max-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;  
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #0071a6;
    text-align: center;

    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    width:185px; /* Pour centrer le menu */
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {
    background-color: #0071a6; 
    color:#FFF;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: none;
}


/*
##############################################################################
Add media query
*/

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }

    ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ul.topnav li a {
        width:auto;  
    }

    ul.topnav {
        width:auto;
    }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens 

Normalement @media screen and (max-width:768px) 

*/
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

    ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
    }

    ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    ul.topnav li a {
        width:auto;  
    }

    ul.topnav {
        width:auto;
    }
}

/*

Pour le menu sticky
*/


.menu {
}

.menu-padding {
    padding-top:0px;
}

.sticky {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.sticky ul.topnav {
    background-color:#0071a6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;

    /*
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    */
}

.sticky ul.topnav li a {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Javascript and Jquery

```
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}

/*
Jquery to make the menu sticky on scroll
*/

$(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = $('.menu');
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

    function scroll() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
            $('.menu').addClass('sticky');
            $('.content').addClass('menu-padding');
        } else {
            $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
            $('.content').removeClass('menu-padding');
        }
    }

    document.onscroll = scroll;
});
```

Html

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">WHO WE ARE </a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">WHAT WE DO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">BLOGS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">GET INVOLVED</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">JOBS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">CONTACT US</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Question**

**Even when i add a new `Ul` inside the menu i do not get a drop down menu ? How can i add a responsive drop down menu to any link there without using bootstrap ?**

Comment: uh..where is the dropdown? the links that should come inside the dropdown, i can't see them.

Comment: you should also add a jsfiddle, an example page is nice, but often not very long lasting after an anwser is posted

Comment: Just refer to one of the many templates already made on Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive Layout with left floating additional div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857226/responsive-layout-with-left-floating-additional-div)